# Join multiple concatenations of attributes with node values using xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I have the following xml content:

```
<ns2:ItemAttributes xml:lang="de-DE">
    <ns2:Creator Role="Role1">Creator One</ns2:Creator>
    <ns2:Creator Role="Role2">Creator Two</ns2:Creator>
    <ns2:Creator Role="Role3">Creator Three</ns2:Creator>
</ns2:ItemAttributes>
```

I'm trying to format and combine this into one line using xpath. 
Something like:

```
string-join(//ns2:Creator/concat(./text(), @Role), ', ')
```

I think, i'm somewhere close, because this:

```
string-join(//ns2:Creator/@Role , ', ')
```

works and gives me a comma-separated list of roles: Role1, Role2, Role3

and this

```
string-join(//ns2:Creator/node(), ', ')
```

combines the values of creators: "Creator One, Creator Two, Creator Three".

I'd like the final output of

```
Role1: Creator One, Role2: Creator Two, Role3: Creator Three
```

Could you please help.

Comment: Getting a bit closer using: string-join(//ns2:Creator/(@Role, node()) , ', ')
Now I have all values, but not that pretty - they are all comma-separated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select `@Role` as the first parameter to your call to `concat()`, and use `.` to select the string value of the context node:

```
string-join($xml//ns2:Creator/concat(@Role, ': ', .), ', ')
```

Instead of `.` you can also use `string()` or `string(.)` which makes explicit the conversion that would otherwise happen implicitly:

```
string-join($xml//ns2:Creator/concat(@Role, ': ', string(.)), ', ')
```

Returns:

```
Role1: Creator One, Role2: Creator Two, Role3: Creator Three
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason in this case I don't get values. The output becomes: ": , : "
So it catches the two items, the colon with a whitespace, but gets no values

Comment: @EugeneBykov Then I suspect you have changed something about either the query or the data, because I have tested this on the same data you provide in your question and the output is correct.

Comment: This is inside teiid sql, may be this matters... The concat processing for example...

Comment: @EugeneBykov That seems likely. However, this is the answer to your question about XQuery. If you have a question about Teiid, you should ask a new question.

Comment: Continued here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534982/join-multiple-concatenations-of-attributes-with-node-values-using-xpath-in-teiid