# Join multiple concatenations of attributes with node values using xpath In Teiid

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery, teiid

This is a very copy of my question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533378/join-multiple-concatenations-of-attributes-with-node-values-using-xpath)
I only need to notice that this is happening in the XMLTABLE of the teiid engine. I'm parsing the following xml content:

```
<AttributeSets>
    <ns2:ItemAttributes xml:lang="de-DE">
        <ns2:Creator Role="Role1">Creator One</ns2:Creator>
        <ns2:Creator Role="Role2">Creator Two</ns2:Creator>
        <ns2:Creator Role="Role3">Creator Three</ns2:Creator>
    </ns2:ItemAttributes>
</AttributeSets>
```

using

```
    Select * From
        XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES( DEFAULT 'http://ns1',
            'http://ns2/default.xsd' as ns2 ),
            'AttributeSets/ns2:ItemAttributes' PASSING x.AttributeSets
        COLUMNS 
            Creator STRING PATH 'string-join(//ns2:Creator/(@Role, node()) , '', '')'
    ) p;
```

Here x.AttributeSets is an xml typed variable with the content from above.

I'm trying to format and combine this into one line using xpath. 
Something like:

```
string-join(//ns2:Creator/concat(./text(), @Role), ', ')
```

I think, i'm somewhere close, because this:

```
string-join(//ns2:Creator/@Role , ', ')
```

works and gives me a comma-separated list of roles: Role1, Role2, Role3

and this

```
string-join(//ns2:Creator/node(), ', ')
```

combines the values of creators: "Creator One, Creator Two, Creator Three".

I'd like the final output of

```
Role1: Creator One, Role2: Creator Two, Role3: Creator Three
```

The most I could get was:

```
 string-join(//ns2:Creator/(@Role, node()) , ', ')
```

This comma-separates all roles and creators into one line. For some reason the concat operator seems no to work.
Could you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following xpath

```
string-join(for $n in /AttributeSets/ItemAttributes/Creator return concat($n/@Role, ':',$n/text()),',')
```

Remember to adjust the selector xpath within the ***for*** as per your source tree context. I assumed document root hence

```
/AttributeSets/ItemAttributes/Creator
```

The documentation for the **string-join** function at [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join) has a pretty similar example.

**Update:**

> I think, i'm somewhere close, because this: ... works and gives me a comma-separated list of roles: Role1, Role2, Role3

Think you were quite close. I tried a small tweak to that and this worked:

```
string-join(//ns2:Creator/concat(@Role, ':', ./text()), ', ')
```

> For some reason the concat operator seems no to work.

Not sure about that, I checked with an online xpath tester [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) and it works perfectly. Infact the online tool accepts your xapth as well with the following output:

```
Creator OneRole1, Creator TwoRole2, Creator ThreeRole3
```

Comment: Thank you! Both your versions work smoothly and as desired!